# Rename button text having no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html as:

```
<div class="k-button k-upload-button">
<input id="files" name="files" type="file" data-role="upload" autocomplete="off">
<span>Select files...</span>
</div>
```

Above html text (tags) i cant change.

I just want to change text :

```
Select files...
```

To :

```
Select file
```

For this i tried:

```
$(".k-button.k-upload-button").find("span").text("Select file");
```

But this did not worked.

Please help me. How can i change the text???

**EDIT1:**

[image]

```
.k-upload-button span:before {
    content: 'Select File';
     position: relative;
     left: 4444px;
    display: inline;
}
.k-upload-button span {
    position: relative;
   left: -4444px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: The only reason what you have would not work is if is run before the HTML for the upload button is added.

Comment: try html() and it should be placed in a callback function. 

`$(".k-button.k-upload-button").find("span").html("Select file");`

Comment: Your code is correct, make sure you do that inside a document ready event handler.

Comment: You code is fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/ngvz9mc6/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes u have said correctly.. But i have writtenit in doccument.ready ... then also its not viewing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### CSS Solution

The span is removed from the viewport and its pseudo child is put back in its place.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/nonex/1/edit)

CSS

```
.k-upload-button span {
    position: relative;
    left: -9999px;
}
.k-upload-button span:before {
    content: 'Select file';
    position: relative;
    left: 9999px;
}
```

Comment: its giving me both text select file and select files...i want to have just a one text "select file" whereas now : "select file select files"

Comment: @misterManSam i solved the problem, but its giving me width too much ... I seted width to 10% in css ... but no effect to it

Comment: @misterManSam plz see Edit 1

Comment: @misterManSam I have added the css i have made

Comment: I need to see **ALL** the CSS that relates to `.k-upload-button` and `.k-button`.

Comment: Did you find what was causing the width issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
document.getElementById("files").innerHTML  = "Select file";
```

Comment: Wondering who upvoted this. `find()` returns a `Jquery` object and it does not have `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @Mathew sorry..  I have corrected my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `.find`

```
$('.k-button').find('span').html('Select File');
```

Or using the `.parent()`

```
$('.k-button').parent().find('span').html('Select File');
```

Or instead of trying hard to select an element why not give itself an `id`

```
$('#d-span').html('Select File');
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6cpofwx8/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span",$('.k-button').parent()).text("New Text");
```